# Subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ that have Baire property, without Choice

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, axiom-of-choice, fields

While sitting through my complex analysis class, beginning with a very low level introduction, the teacher mentioned the obvious subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, and I then wondered whether this was unique.  When I got back to my computer, I looked on google and came up with [this](http://camoo.freeshell.org/cfield.isor.html), which indicated that is not.  However, the proof given there makes heavy use of Choice, and based on similar things, I am guessing that this cannot be avoided.

Define DC($\omega_1$) as:

 For all [trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28set_theory%29) $T$, $\quad$ $T\:$ has a branch $\ $ or $\ $ $T\:$ has a chain of length $\omega_1$ $\quad$.

which, if I haven't messed up the simplification, ZF proves is equivalent to the definition given at shelah.logic.at/files/446.ps .

Does $\ ZF+DC(\omega_1)\ $ prove that there is a unique subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ which is both isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and has Baire property?

Comment: +1 just for blowing my mind with the fact that there are subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ other than $\mathbb{R}$!

Comment: @Zev: The fact that $\mathbb C$ has uncountably many field automorphisms does not seem so surprising to me. After all the only obstruction that keeps $\mathbb R$ from having many automorphisms is the fact that its order can be described algebraically, hence is preserved. Since there is no such obstruction on $\mathbb C$, there should be plenty of automorphisms, and in fact there are.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the formatting?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation Tobias. I found the result very counterintuitive until you pointed out that there was no reason to have that intuition to begin with :)

Comment: @Harry, What does there seem to be wrong with the formatting?

Comment: @Ricky: Your translation of DC_omega1 to trees is not correct.  The above statement is obviously false, for instance since clearly the one element tree has no chain of length omega1.

Comment: Just a comment - The first link should be http://camoo.freeshell.org/cfield.isor.html instead of http://camoo.freeshell.org/cfield.isor to make it more readable.